# grouping with oracle with clause

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table from which i am trying to pull the frequency distribution by age-group and score-group. Below is the query I am running.

```
   with age_map as (select distinct age,case when age is not null 
                                        and AGE>=16 AND AGE<36 then '16-35'
                                      when age is not null and  AGE>=36 AND 
                                      AGE<56  then '36-56'
                                      when age is not null and  AGE>=56 then 
                                      '56+'
                                      when age is null then 'NA'
                                  end as age_group
                     from rec_table
                     where monthofsale = 'Apr 2017'
                      )
      select name,location,b.age_group,sum(weight),count(*)
      from rec_table a, age_map b
      where a.age = b.age
      group by name,location,b.age_group
```

When running the query, I keep getting the error:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

I am pretty sure I am including all the columns. So, wondering if this is not correct?

My expected output is:

```
      Name     location    age_group   weight count
       x          y         16-35         15   3
       p          q         36-56         48   7
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group by error is coming from the with clause:

Do the select like this:

```
select age, case when age is not null and AGE>=16 AND AGE<36 then '16-35'
                 when age is not null and  AGE>=36 AND AGE<56  then '36-56'
                 when age is not null and  AGE>=56 then  '56+'
                 when age is null then 'NA'
                 end as age_group
from rec_table
where monthofsale = 'Apr 2017'
group by age, case when age is not null and AGE>=16 AND AGE<36 then '16-35'
                 when age is not null and  AGE>=36 AND AGE<56  then '36-56'
                 when age is not null and  AGE>=56 then  '56+'
                 when age is null then 'NA'
                 end
```

Comment: Thanks, removed with clause and directly used the case in group-by. Seems to work now.